# Jquery collapsible toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, content-management-system, jquery-ui-accordion

I have tried to work with Jquery accordion and it seems working for me but when I want to use the collapsible/toggle mode where I can see all the tabs open for me then I am facing the problem. I have my own CMS and below is the code for HTML. "I want to see the div part by clicking the heading". I don't want to change anything in HTML part and just want to use JQuery here. HTML PART, JS PART, JQUERY as following

```
    <div class="js-toggle-headline sf-toggle-headline">
        <h3 class="active">Headline 1</h3>
        <div>$charClone{Content Part 1</div>
        <h3>Headline 2</h3>
        <div>$charClone{Content Part 2$\ }{30}</div>
        <h3>Headline 3</h3>
        <div>$charClone{Content Part 3$\ }{30}</div>
    </div>
```

Javascript and Jquery

```
$$js_toggle{$hashTable.new
{selector}{h3}
{target}{div}
{container}{.js-toggle-headline}
{animation}{slide}
{initialize}{$java.new{java.lang.Boolean}{1}}
{toggleClass}{active}}


$(function(){
            $('.js-toggle-headline').accordion({
                heightStyle: 'target',
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                autoHeight: true
            });
        });
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what's trying to be achieved? ... is there a better way to explain? Though I'm not familiar with the `$$js_toggle` syntax part, but ignoring that, clicking the headings seem to show/hide the related div section, which appears to be working.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I actually want to show the toggle where if I click the one heading it will be open, then click the second heading, it will also be open but the first one will be stay open and up to so on. I think you got the understanding. but problem is that I don't want to change anything from HTML part. I just want to use this same HTML and along with want to use JS and Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *thought* there were API options to make it work without collapsing the other sections, but apparently not. However, the behavior can be achieved with some mods, but does involve a minor html change. See the three code comments for the specific changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                      // add div in the selector
    $('.js-toggle-headline > div').accordion({
        heightStyle: 'target',
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        header: 'h3'  // set the designated accordion header element
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <div class="js-toggle-headline sf-toggle-headline">
      <div> <!-- add a div wrapper to each group -->
        <h3>Headline 1</h3>
        <div>Content Part 1</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Headline 2</h3>
        <div>Content Part 2</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Headline 3</h3>
        <div>Content Part 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

=====

Another way, without extra html, to achieve a similar accordion effect, but withOUT using the accordion provided by jqueryui, but uses jquery for the handling: (obviously, will not be as fancy-looking, and without animation)

Of course, keep the jqueryui for other widget needs.

```js
// handler for each h3 with the section class.
$('h3.section').on('click', function() {
      let child = $(this).next();
      if (child.is(':hidden')) {
          child.show();
      } else {
          child.hide();
      }
});
```

```css
#accordion > h3 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#accordion > div {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion"> <!-- I kept the same ID for CSS -->
      <h3 class="section">Headline 1</h3>
      <div>Content Part 1</div>
      <h3 class="section">Headline 2</h3>
      <div>Content Part 2</div>
      <h3 class="section">Headline 3</h3>
      <div>Content Part 3</div>
      <h3 class="section">Headline 4</h3>
      <div>Content Part 4</div>
</div>
<!-- I added class="section" to each h3, in case other h3 elements might exist -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but could it be possible without adding extra div? because I don't want to edit the HTML part.

Comment: Probably, but would not use the accordion from jqueryui. See the updated portion of the answer that does not use jqueryui whatsoever for the accordion.